# How to concatenate/combine features extracted from a CNN with other scalar features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have a data set with 10, 000 images, and each image has 5 binary labels. I'm trying to train 5 classifiers for these 5 classes. I decided to extract features from images using a CNN like VGG or ResNet. What I want to do next, is to combine these "deep features" with 4 of the binary labels, and predict the missing label.
Combining these features is where I'm having trouble.

Let's say the feature extracted from VGG 16 for each image, is a vector with size of 4096. How should I add the other features to this feature vector?

I did some search, and found a similar problem. The Iris data set. to classify flower images, each flower has some labels, like petal length and petal width. The feature vector for each image, is simple a list with two values, petal length and petal width.

Should I just create a vector with size equal to 4100, and add my other 4 labels at the end of it?! Or should I create a 1 * 5 numpy array for each image, the first element in this array being the 4096 vector, and the other 4 elements set to the 4 scalar labels of the image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to provide your convolutional features and your additional labels as two separate inputs and concatenate them inside your final classifier.

Minimal working example:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications import VGG16
import numpy as np

# Some random images, labels and target label
images = np.random.rand(10, 64, 64, 3)
labels = np.random.randint(0, 1, size=(10, 4))
target = np.random.randint(0, 1, size=(10, 1))

# Extract VGG16 features for the images
image_input = Input((64, 64, 3))
model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
features = model.predict(images)
features = np.reshape(features, (10, -1))  # 2048 features per image 

# Two input layers: one for the image features, one for additional labels
feature_input = Input((2048,), name='feature_input')
label_input = Input((4, ), name='label_input')

# Concatenate the features
concatenate_layer = Concatenate(name='concatenation')([feature_input, label_input]) 
dense = Dense(16)(concatenate_layer)
output = Dense(1, name='output_layer', activation='sigmoid')(dense)

# To define the model, pass list of input layers
model = Model(inputs=[feature_input, label_input], outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# To fit the model, pass a list of inputs arrays
model.fit(x=[features, labels], y=target)
```

Also have a look at [Keras' functional API guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/), which contains plenty of examples of multi-input/multi-output models.